# [Autoware] Create custom map - osm file version

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to pass custom map using [map publisher](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/9a3c3289b153f0b4c29895f3a2c33f92f3508f9c/src/tools/autoware_auto_avp_demo/param/map_publisher_vehicle.param.yaml) and [lanelet2 map provider](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/9a3c3289b153f0b4c29895f3a2c33f92f3508f9c/src/tools/autoware_auto_avp_demo/param/lanelet2_map_provider.param.yaml) configs. Using recorded pointcloud data, [ndt mapper](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/9a3c3289b153f0b4c29895f3a2c33f92f3508f9c/src/mapping/ndt_mapping_nodes/launch/ndt_mapper.launch.py) and [vector map builder](https://tools.tier4.jp/vector_map_builder_ll2/) I already created a new pcd map with corresponding semantic map. Then I changed mentioned above config to load new files.

1. I couldn't load pcd map. Looking into default .pcd file I noticed some differences. Ndt mapper produce pointcloud map using  4 channels (x, y, z, intensity). So I just remove the last channel and map was loaded successfully. But is it possible to load properly 4 channels .pcd file?
2. I still can't load .osm file. Again, there are some differences:

- part of autoware included file:

`<osm version='0.6' generator='JOSM'>`

`<node id='1001' visible='true' version='1' lat='37.38143282929' lon='-121.90825956337'>`

`<tag k='ele' v='-1.4483755826950073' />`

`</node>`

- part of my custom file (created with vector map builder):

`<osm generator="VMB">`

`<MetaInfo format_version="1" map_version="4"/>`

`<node id="1" lat="" lon="">`

`<tag k="mgrs_code" v="99XXX000000"/>`

`<tag k="local_x" v="52.9384"/>`

`<tag k="local_y" v="38.5049"/>`

`<tag k="ele" v="0"/>`

`</node>`

In rviz I can see new pcd map without semantic map. The `/had_maps/viz_had_map` topic returns error `Contains invalid floating point values (nans or infs)`.
Are these differences in the .osm file version causing the maps to load incorrectly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384072/%5Bautoware%5D-create-custom-map---osm-file-version/) by [definitive](https://answers.ros.org/users/57454/definitive/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2021-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @definitive , have a look at my Q&A [HERE](https://answers.ros.org/question/376240/how-to-build-correct-lanelet2-map-for-autowareauto/)

---

Originally posted by [Aleksandr Savel'ev](https://answers.ros.org/users/73343/aleksandr-savel%27ev/) with karma: 146 on 2021-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1